# How to color part of the Board using JSXGraph?

Tags: jsxgraph

I'd like to color the Board over a line using JSXGraph.

I'm drawing lines on the Board and use "polygon" to color the common space above / under these lines.

However there are cases when "polygon" is not a solution as I want to color basically the whole Board above / below these lines. (When the common space is above / below them.) Is there any way to color "above lines" or "below lines" without using "polygon"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for the element *inequality*, see https://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/Inequality.html .
You'll find examples how to use it there.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!